# How to kill another script in bash if it's already running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a hardware button on my Raspberry Pi. If I press it the script `handle.sh` is called which calls another script named `do.sh`. I want to kill `do.sh` if I press the button a second time. My desire is to toggle the script. First press run `do.sh`, second press exit this script.

My idea was to get the PID of `do.sh`. If there is already an instance of `do.sh`, `handle.sh` should kill the process of `do.sh`.

My pseudo code:

handle.sh

```
if do.sh not running {
    run do.sh
} else if do.sh is running {
    kill do.sh
    // do more stuff
}
```

do.sh

```
echo date
arecord -D hw:3,0 -f cd -r 44100 test.wav
```

Comment: What is your final goal ? Do you want to lock the script if another instances is running or really kill the latest to replace with the new call ?

Comment: I want to start an audio recording script with `arecord` or `ffmpeg` if I press the button. On the second button press I want to exit the recording, save the file and upload it to my cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if pgrep -f do.sh &>/dev/null; then
    pkill -f do.sh
    // do more stuff
else
    ./do.sh
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I can determine if my script is already running. Have problems with killing ffmpeg and my script. They are running nonstop. I will start a new question if I can't find a solution by myself.